# Time series normalization by event

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Suppose I've a python dict as follows, for each product, key is timestamp and value is price of product at that timestamp.

```
data_dict = {
'product_1' : {1: 415, 2: 550, 3: 0,   4: 550, 5: 600},
'product_2' : {1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 300, 4: 0,   5: 300},
'product_3' : {1: 500, 2: 400, 3: 0,   4: 500, 5: 500},
'product_4' : {1: 0,   2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 300, 5: 300}
 }
```

It's very common in timeseries analysis to be renormalizing many timeseries by some event, assume we consider the event as the timestamp when the product is free. I would like to get a table that's of this structure

```
           | -3  | -2  | -1  | 0 | +1  | +2  | +3  | +4  |
---------------------------------------------------------
product_1  | NA  | 415 | 550 | 0 | 550 | 600 | NA  | NA  |
product_2  | 400 | 300 | 300 | 0 | 300 | NA  | NA  | NA  |
product_3  | NA  | 500 | 400 | 0 | 500 | 500 | NA  | NA  |
product_4  | NA  | NA  | NA  | 0 | 200 | 200 | 300 | 300 |
```

Is there some way to do this easily using pandas for python? I'm sure tons of data-science guys have had to do something similar at some point. If not, would really appreciate if pandas guys could add some functionality for something like this in future! In mean time, any suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) method, but that tends to be in-efficient if you have many columns;

So starting with this frame:

```
>>> df
   product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4
1        415        400        500          0
2        550        300        400        200
3          0        300          0        200
4        550          0        500        300
5        600        300        500        300
```

you define a synchronizing function as in:

```
>>> def sync(ts):
...     vals = ts.values
...     n, k = len(vals), np.where(vals == 0)[0][0]
...     return Series(vals, np.arange(-k, n - k))
```

and apply it column-wise:

```
>>> df.apply(sync).T
            -3   -2   -1   0    1    2    3    4
product_1  NaN  415  550   0  550  600  NaN  NaN
product_2  400  300  300   0  300  NaN  NaN  NaN
product_3  NaN  500  400   0  500  500  NaN  NaN
product_4  NaN  NaN  NaN   0  200  200  300  300
```

`.T` at the end for transpose.

Comment: Yes, I gave a mock example here, but I am working with a dataframe with over 8000 columns and close to 300 rows, and rows will keep adding up. Thanks for your input! Helps a lot.

Comment: Hey, I made a change to mock example above, product 3 is free on day 2 and 3. And in expected structure, i wish -1 to reflect the non-zero value and similarly with +1, as shown. Could you help me with same?

Comment: @harshal.c: that's a very different question.  Invalidating an answer by changing your question isn't quite cricket.

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed the question, but I didn't invalidate your answer, well, I will change the question back, I just realized I hadn't been generic enough. Thanks though.