# Time series normalization by event - Generic version

Tags: python, pandas

This question is just a generic version of a question I have already posted, [Time series normalization by event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723459/time-series-normalization-by-event).

Suppose I've a python dict as follows, for each product, key is timestamp and value is price of product at that timestamp.

```
data_dict = {
'product_1' : {1: 415, 2: 550, 3: 0,   4: 550, 5: 600},
'product_2' : {1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 300, 4: 0,   5: 300},
'product_3' : {1: 500, 2: 0  , 3: 0,   4: 500, 5: 500},
'product_4' : {1: 0,   2: 200, 3: 200, 4: 300, 5: 300}
 }
```

It's very common in timeseries analysis to be renormalizing many timeseries by some event, assume we consider the event as the timestamp when the product is free. In generic version I allow for the product to be free for multiple days. I would like to get a table that's of this structure.

```
           | -3  | -2  | -1  | 0 | +1  | +2  | +3  | +4  |
---------------------------------------------------------
product_1  | NA  | 415 | 550 | 0 | 550 | 600 | NA  | NA  |
product_2  | 400 | 300 | 300 | 0 | 300 | NA  | NA  | NA  |
product_3  | NA  | NA  | 500 | 0 | 500 | 500 | NA  | NA  |
product_4  | NA  | NA  | NA  | 0 | 200 | 200 | 300 | 300 |
```

Is there some way to do this easily using pandas for python? I'm sure tons of data-science guys have had to do something similar at some point. If not, would really appreciate if pandas guys could add some functionality for something like this in future! In mean time, any suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Just building upon the answer of the restricted case here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33723633/1853020

I modified the function to introduce left and right limits:

```
def sync(arr):
    shift_l = np.where(arr.values == 0)[0][0]
    shift_r = np.where(arr.values == 0)[0][-1]
    if shift_l == shift_r:
        return pd.Series(arr.values, np.arange(-shift_l , len(arr.values) - shift_l))
    else:
        arr2 = np.delete(arr.values, [x for x in range(shift_l, shift_r)])
        return pd.Series(arr2, np.arange(-shift_l, len(arr2) - shift_l))
```

Then just applying it to the pandas dataframe created out of data_dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(data_dict).apply(sync).T

            -3   -2   -1   0    1    2    3    4
product_1  NaN  415  550   0  550  600  NaN  NaN
product_2  400  300  300   0  300  NaN  NaN  NaN
product_3  NaN  NaN  500   0  500  500  NaN  NaN
product_4  NaN  NaN  NaN   0  200  200  300  300
```